# HAXM doesn't seem to work with AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I've gone through many threads in SO but I can't get an answer.

I did everything according to [instruction](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows). Twice actually. I chose both [x86 and x86_64 for CPU type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL5BX.png). `haxm_check.exe` is showing [everything works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Ii8.png). `sc query intelhaxm` also appears to report [everything OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kno5L.png).

Performance I get: I have to wait for about a minute until a phone app opens and a minute again to get back to home screen.

My CPU is i5-3210M @ 2,5GHz, So I don't think this is a problem to at least get a decent performance.

Answer (score 0):

try lowering the device ram size.
so go to the AVD Manager and press the pencil icon for editing the device.
set it at 512mb first. then try again.
this is the only thing i can think of with the information you gave.